# jQuery: Chaining multiple functions gives Uncaught Typeerror

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm attempting to chain multiple function calls in my script, but I keep getting `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tablesorter(...).tablesorterPager is not a function` whenever I try to get it on my webpage.

The code in question is formatted like this:

```
function InitializeTableSorter() {
    var pagerOptions = {
        //object definitions in here
    }; 

    $("#transaction").tablesorter({
        //function stuff in here    
    }).tablesorterPager(pagerOptions);
}
```

I'm using the [Tablesorter plugin](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html) here, which uses the `tableSorter` and `tablesorterPager` functions.

What went wrong here? Did I miss anything?

Comment: Have you included jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js in addition to tablesorter?

Comment: That would give another error, OP is probably missing the `jquery.tablesorter.pager.js` plugin.

Comment: @Timmetje I have the appropriate plugin files installed as well.

Comment: Not all plugins are chainable. Some return objects that aren't the element passed in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have the appropriate plugin files installed (in the appropriate order if order matters)

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tablesorter(...).tablesorterPager is not a function

is usually encountered when there are conflicts between jQuery and other libraries. To stay out of trouble, call `$.noConflict()` and don't forget to run your jQuery code after the document is `ready`

```
$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  function InitializeTableSorter() {
    var pagerOptions = {
        //object definitions in here
    }; 

    $("#transaction").tablesorter({
        //function stuff in here    
    }).tablesorterPager(pagerOptions);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var pagerOptions = {
        //object definitions in here
    }; 

    $("#transaction").tablesorter({
        //function stuff in here    
    }).tablesorterPager(pagerOptions);
});
```

Use this method bottom of the page.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is causing the error
.tablesorterPager(pagerOptions);

Try with this:

```
function InitializeTableSorter() {
   var pagerOptions = {
       //object definitions in here
   }; 

   $("#transaction").tablesorter(pagerOptions);
}
```