# How to solve Uncaught TypeError: $(...).carouFredSel is not a function at

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have MVC Project, and i have created ActionResult, with this code in View:

```
@{
    Layout = String.Empty;
}
<div class="weather-widget-container">
    <!--<div class="weather-widget-title">Метео</div>-->
    <ul style="margin-top: 5px;  float: left" id="vremenska"></ul>
    <img id="weather-loading" style="height:16px; width:11px; margin-top: 5px; float: right;  margin-right: 5px; " src="/vremenskaX/ikoni/loading.gif" />
</div>


<script>
        window.RostuseFunction = [];
</script>

<script>
        for (var i = 0, length = window.RostuseFunction.length; i < length; i++) {
            window.RostuseFunction[i]();
        }
</script>



<script src="../Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../vremenskaX/js/jquery.carouFredSel-6.2.1-packed.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../vremenskaX/meteopro2.js"></script>

<link href="~/Content/meteopro2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

When i send request to : localhost/Vremenska/Index page is ok, but when i call from another page localhost/Vesti/Aktuelno with RenderAction:

```
@{Html.RenderAction("Index", "Vremenska");}
```

When i open localhost/Vesti/Aktuelno i have this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).carouFredSel is not a function
>
> at SuccessMeteo (meteopro2.js:18)
>
> at Object. (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4)
>
> at i (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2)
>
> at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2)
>
> at A (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4)
>
> at HTMLScriptElement.c (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4)
>
> at HTMLScriptElement.dispatch (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:3)
>
> at HTMLScriptElement.q.handle (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:3)

What is wrong, and how to solve it?

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45289832/jquery-chaining-multiple-functions-gives-uncaught-typeerror/45304082#45304082

Comment: Thank you, i solve the problem.

Comment: was the linked answer useful?

Comment: Yes of course i added just $.noConflict(); to code and work property now. Thank you again

Comment: Happy I could help :) an upvote would be appriciated (to help distinguish useful answers from the rest)