# Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).tablesorter is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, typo3, typo3-6.2.x, typo3-7.6.x

I have a typo3 plugin hat works fine in typo3 6.2.31 now I migrate to 7.6.23. I have several problems with jQuery libraries. I often got this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).tablesorter is not a function

Or

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tablesorter is not a function

The library is loaded correctly. Is there a way to fix this issue? Thanks.

Comment: You say that the library is loaded correctly yet the error would state otherwise. Are you loading the library async, and is the path correct?

Comment: Also try to check if you load jquery more than once, that's also not recommended according to this: https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/issues/1179

Comment: Path is correct. I load jquery in default.html of the backend application

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45289832/jquery-chaining-multiple-functions-gives-uncaught-typeerror/45304082#45304082

Comment: Not really a dublicate. In my case there are typo3 problems I think. Sometimes it works now I've done this: `TYPO3.jQuery(".table.sortable").tablesorter();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A working solution is:

```
TYPO3.jQuery(".table.sortable").tablesorter();
```

Answer (score 2):

Check that there is a loaded tablesorter plugin first before the tyop3 plugin, sounds like ideal sort order would be:

1. jQuery library
2. Tablesorter plugin
3. Typo3 plugin

Comment: I load the libs in the backend module default.html

Comment: 1.) jQuery, then Tablesorter